# Is it possible to get a bottomNavBar without icons / with text only

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to get a bottom navigation bar, but the Tabs should be text-only. The problem is, that icon is a required property of BottomNavigationBarItem().

Edit: I got it working using a tab bar as bottom nav bar, but @Fernando Rocha 's solution seems to work less tricky and works better. To sum it up, simply add "size: 0" to each icon (you will still need an icon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used size 0 at icon size and it worked

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home, size: 0),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business, size: 0),
            title: Text('Business'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school, size: 0),
            title: Text('School'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: You should note that material design doesn't aprove this though: https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#anatomy

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Icon(null),
  title: Text('Just Text'),
)
```

to achieve this.

With this approach there will still be an empty space where the Icon is "supposed" to go. With @Fernando Rocha 's approach it looks like the text is centered.

Answer (score 0):

I used tabs instead :

```
static const List<Tab> _tabs = [
  Tab(text: "A"),
  Tab(text: "AA"),
  Tab(text: "AAA")
];

return WillPopScope(
    child: DefaultTabController(
      length: _tabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          // color: Color(0xFF3F5AA6),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 11),
          child: TabBar(
            // labelColor: Colors.white,
            // unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white60,
            // indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7, horizontal: 23),
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            onTap: (int index) {
               setState(() {
                 _selectedIndex = index;
               });
            },
            tabs: _tabs,
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: _pages[_selectedIndex]
        ),
      ),
    ),
    onWillPop: () async {
      return Navigator.canPop(context);
    }
);
```